# Can I maintain two active Stack Exchange logins in the same browser session?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I use several Stack Exchange communities for work.  All are linked to my work Google account. Now I want to participate in another community using my personal email address. I do *not* want to have these two accounts talk to each other; I just want a business account for work communities and a personal account for hobbies, homeowner stuff, etc.

I was able to create a personal Stack Exchange account linked to my personal Google account using a *private* browser window.  But if I go back to the main browser window where I am already logged on to my work communities, I can't find any way to log in to Stack Exchange with my personal account. Do I have to start a separate browser session every time I want to use a different Stack Exchange account?

**Update** As clarified in the comments, "incognito mode" is Google Chrome's term for a private browsing session. I am asking about staying logged in to multiple StackExchange accounts *without* using a private/incognito window.

Comment: There's always "Incognito" mode...

Comment: Incognito is the Google Chrome term for  Firefox's Private. Either one requires re-logging in every time. I want to stay logged in to multiple accounts, the same way that I do with Gmail.

Comment: I am stuck on that for similar, but different reasons. Can we request this capability as a new feature to SE? It also allows two users to share the same computer and browser (think a shared team resource) at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, right now we do not support switching between accounts like Google does. You'll need to use different browsers (if you want to maintain being logged in to both accounts at the same time) or log out/log in when you want to switch.

I believe creating multiple browser *profiles* (Chrome supports that, not sure about others) should also work fine, but I haven't tried it in a while myself.

Comment: Firefox makes profiles pretty painless as well. Both, I believe, allow having multiple profiles open simultaneously, which is handy for separating personal / professional stuff when that's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer and the suggestion to use profiles. As best I can tell, profiles would allow me to have two copies of Firefox running in parallel but would require a different set of bookmarks, tabs, browser history, etc., with a different Firefox logon if I want to sync all that across devices. That's more separation than I'm looking for. I'll probably go with a Private session (a bit of a pain with two-factor Google authentication) or a different browser.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox has "containers" - essentially groups of tabs whose cookies, etc. are kept separate within the same profile. The feature is built-in, but the management is via an official add-on called [Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/).

> #### [What you can do with Multi-Account Containers](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers#w_what-you-can-do-with-multi-account-containers)
>
> - Log in to multiple accounts on a single website at the same time. For example, if you have a personal Gmail account and a work Gmail
>   account, you can log in to both accounts in separate containers.
>
>   ...
> - Assign a website to a container, so that a specific website will always open in a specific container. This helps protect from
>   accidents, stopping you from accidentally visiting a shopping site in
>   your banking container, for example.
> - Hide and Show: If you use your browser for both Work and Personal tasks and don’t want to be thinking about “Work” when you come home,
>   you can “Hide” your Work tabs and proceed with your Personal tasks.
>   Then the next day, when you are back at work, you can “Hide” your
>   Personal tabs and “Show” your Work tabs.
>
>   ...

I find it indispensable at work for testing the same site via different users, and for accessing different AWS accounts at the same time and so on all in tabs in the same window.