# Allow moving an existing Stack Exchange account to a new user account if different from the main category in that user account

Tags: feature-request, login, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

**UPDATE: shortened, and with the official Stack Exchange (in the following: SE) categories.**

This is a spin-off from [Move an existing Stack Exchange account to a new user account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359492/move-an-existing-stack-exchange-account-to-a-new-user-account).

You could for example see the need for such a feature in [Can I maintain two active StackExchange logins in the same browser session?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277378/can-i-maintain-two-active-stackexchange-logins-in-the-same-browser-session):

> I just want a business account for work communities and a personal
> account for hobbies, homeowner stuff, etc.

This feature request is to allow SE accounts of a different category than the mainly used category of that user account to be split off to a user account where that moved SE account has not been used yet. The categories in question are the official SE categories:

- Technology
- Life / Arts
- Culture / Recreation
- Science
- Other
- perhaps: Professional
- perhaps: Business
- (I would also add exceptions for Meta SE accounts perhaps, but not sure about this).

These categories are taken from SE, see:

[image]

or:

[image]

It is for those users who start quite a few accounts as a beginner and only later realize that splitting up the accounts in two users is allowed at all. Or it is for those users who change their job or have other reasons to be less transparent about "who they are" - for example, for privacy reasons.

I was not even aware of this issue until I realized that I do not want the English language account between my tech accounts, and I did not know that having more than one user account is even best practice here: I thought it would not even be allowed, since there is the risk that you vote and accept your own questions.

In order to avoid any misuse, such moving of an SE account should cost the association bonus or even more, which should be marked in the profile's reputation chart. After a movement, minus points should be possible. This is just a side-note and not fully needed perhaps. It is a mere point of discussion, the feature request is about the general idea instead.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I want to have the already used SE account *with its content* to be moved to another user so that I do not need to hide it there, since I do not want to hide it at all. I just do not want to show alltogether, and what I want to show depends on the context (a job application is just *one* of many examples).

Comment: While I favour being able to have different thematic accounts for different stacks, I don't think "tech", "non-tech" is a useful distinction in many cases. For example, SO is a tech site. But what about [math.se] or [stats.se]? You can very well have a question there related to something you want to do with code. You can also ask questions on [conlang.se] (non-tech) about a game you're making and you're otherwise active on [gamedev.se]. Trying to label "exceptional stuff" starts becoming quite hard in the face of all that.

Comment: @VLAZ It's probably a little known *secret*, despite appearing in the footer, that there's a pre-defined categorical split; simply [click on the ▶️ to see the sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeqGp.jpg) that comprise "Technology" vs "Science".

Comment: @questionto42 could you explain why you want this? What problem would it solve? What would it allow you to do that you cannot do now? I've re-read the question three times and I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. And do consider that the categories are not well defined. Is Biology a tech site? How about Bioinformatics? What do non-tech sites have in common? Why would anyone want to group them together?

Comment: @VLAZ good point, it is then a question of how you name it. I see Cross Validated as a classical tech site, while English Language Usage is not. And things that are typically hobbies and not meant for the usual IT could be kept aside. Even the Astronomy Stack Exchange would not be "tech" then, and yes, we should find a better name then. This request is not about finding the best cut or name here, it is more the general idea that should be discussed. Science vs. technology is not the question.

Comment: @terdon This is a spin-off from https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359492/move-an-existing-stack-exchange-account-to-a-new-user-account. And problems could be: you share your username on the long run. On the short run, you might not need to split among multiple users. But if you need it later, for example because you do not want to share your various communities with anyone who can look up your profile (hiding is not a good workaround), or if you have become a teacher and you do not want the pupils to look at what you do in the didactics community, then you need it.

Comment: Then you open a new account. It seems needlessly complicated to have a whole functionality for something that will only be used rarely and will likely be abused often (we have enough trouble tracking sock puppets already).

Comment: @terdon Needlessly complicated is one view. I would rather say that you make it too simple. Even your question about what could be the problem at all (which is something that goes without saying here) is already too easy-going. I have made the very small mistake of opening a non-tech account on my normal "tech" user. What can happen to you after a short time can also happen to you after a long time. It is not only a problem of a beginner. What you want to share can change over life-time and due to outer reasons. And you do not want to just delete or hide your work then.

Answer (score 8):

> This feature request is to allow splitting up a collection of thematically different Stack Exchange accounts among multiple user accounts.

First off, why limit the feature request only to 'thematically different accounts'? The easiest way to allow this would be ... to allow this for any and all site profiles, regardless of their theme. Each site has its own theme already, which determines what is on- and off topic on such a site.

Making categories is easy, but arguing that the sites in these categories are similar or different enough to make splitting off a profile okay or forbidden is not. Someone that wants to split off [their profile on the arduino site because it's just a hobby](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name) from their Stack Overflow profile and put them under two different accounts would be barred from doing so, as both are grouped as 'technology'.

While it does sound nice to be able to split off a profile instead of hide things, **it's likely to cause more trouble than create benefits that can't be had already** by using the feature to [hide site profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290092/369802) or creating a second account.  So I'm going to say allowing users to do this is a very bad idea.

Allowing people to just move site profiles between accounts would likely be a cause of many messes and open up new ways of abuse. As a quick example: If people can transfer one site profile to a sock, they can e.g. earn the association bonus for that sock account. And voilà: now the sock can participate in a sockpuppet ring and upvote posts, without ever having to even try and gain the first few reputation points. Without any restrictions, you could even move one site profile from sock, to sock, to sock, to sock....

Networkwide suspensions could become useless. Keeping track of notorious troublemakers and trolls becomes harder. Is there anyone that wants to buy an SO account with a bit of rep and a good question, that allows you to flag and comment but won't get question banned as easily? I've got a PayPal...

Comment: The feature request is meant for thematically different accounts, and this shall prevent the mess that you are fearing. If you want to discuss a feature request that does not distinguish between such categories, it is another discussion - which will certainly have no success, I agree. The rest of the post is of course good to be discussed.

Comment: @questionto42 Even for thematically different accounts, the messes still count, that doesn't change. Each site has its own topic, so each site could be seen as "thematically different". You already point out that you wouldn't put tech didactics under tech... Making categories is easy, arguing that they're different enough to prevent or allow splitting off site profiles isn't.

Comment: Then you have not understood the request. It is essentially about the broad categories behind, and best example is tech vs. non-tech (and exceptions that are in between, like tech didactics; this is an exception, and other exceptions are also possible, the main rule would still be to look at *single* categories, which would be the usual case of 90 % of the Stack Exchanges). The messes are by far not the same as what you describe in a scenario where you can move whatever SE account to whatever user account.

Comment: "*First off, why limit yourself only to 'thematically different accounts'?*" counter question - why is this a problem? I maintain several thematically different profiles across websites. I associate them with different email accounts. Some of them are the more "professional" with my main email and then there are accounts based on my hobbies with a second email. I find the separation quite useful. I wouldn't want to cross the accounts. I don't see why others doing similar but on the Stack Exchange network would be questioned and discouraged.

Comment: @VLAZ there's nothing wrong with *having* accounts that are thematically different. My question is to illustrate the point that limiting the ability *to split off existing site profiles from an account* based on the "theme" of the site profile and the "theme" of the account you want to split off of, makes no sense. Why should someone that wants to split off [their arduino and drones hobbies](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name) from their SO profile be limited because all three are themed "technology"? I've edited to reflect this is about the limitation in the feature request :)

Comment: @VLAZ I have not requested anyone to cross the accounts. I want to reach your way of doing it, after realizing too late that two or even more accounts would make sense. That is something a beginner might not think of when adding a few communities for fun at first. Or she might change her mind later. Sooner or later, it can happen to any user, beginner or professional. Arduino and drones hobbies are still tech in my eyes. What I do not see that techy is sociological, philosophical, language-wise and other similarly non-tech Stack Exchanges.

Comment: @questionto42 if a user has created profiles that they're unhappy with, they can [delete those profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/369802) without having to delete their entire account. But, from the faq on [post-dissociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746): "You should be willing to stand by all content you contribute to our network." and "You need to keep in mind that everything you post on the Internet is permanent, with your name permanently attached to it.". Moving profiles between accounts won't fix that any more than post-dissociation or deleting an account will.

Comment: So, think before you post, that goes for everything on the internet and especially for SE. Besides, implementing this feature request wouldn't be done *solely* for your purpose. The part about drones and arduino is to illustrate another use case where a user might want to divide between 'hobby' (private life, if you like) and 'professional' (suitable for the public). While they are still tech in your opinion and as such no problem for you on 1 account, it is an example that illustrates how dividing things into tech and non-tech will not make for a useful tool many people can use.

Comment: Having a hobby like drones is a techy topic, be it hobby or not, it will not harm you if you apply, there will be nothing really private revealed by it, it can support you in your professional presentation if you have this hobby. If you instead have too many non-tech Stack Exchanges within a professional profile, it can fall back on you, and you might realise this too late. Perhaps call it tech-supportive and tech-distant, or tech-positive and tech-negative. It is about the basic idea anyway.